# Javascript - how to render an output by typing three (or more) alphabets into the input?

Tags: javascript, html

I am making an html page which is a typer of a foreign script.

my progress: [HERE](https://jstrieb.github.io/urlpages/editor/#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)

Here's the entire javascript:

```
function getReplacedText(latinText) {
            if (!latinText) {
                return "";
        }
            var replacedText = "";
            for (var i = 0, len = latinText.length; i < len; i++) {
                var curLetter = latinText[i];
                var pos1Txt = latinText[i + 1];
                var pos2Txt = latinText[i + 2];
                if (!(curLetter == "")) {
                    var dualLetter = latreplaced[curLetter + pos1Txt];
                    if (dualLetter) {
                        replacedText += dualLetter;
                        i++;
                        continue;
                    }
                }

                replacedText += latreplaced[curLetter] || curLetter;
            }
            return replacedText;
        }
        
     
        var latreplaced = {

"u":"う",
"ku":"く",
"tsu":"つ",

        };

        function onLatinTextChange(txt) {
            var replacedTextareaElem = document.getElementById("replaced_textarea");
            var div = document.createElement("div");
            var replacedHtmlEntities = getReplacedText(txt);
            div.innerHTML = replacedHtmlEntities;
            replacedTextareaElem.value = div.innerText;
        }
```

The purpose of this project is to create a virtual phonetic keyboard to type certain forign scripts by only using Latin alphabets, without its keyboard setting installed.

Basically, if you enter an alphabet into the input `<textarea>`, it renders its corresponding foreign alphabet. (For instance, input 'u' > output 'う', input 'ku' > output 'く')

Here is my problem: So far I have enabled rendering an output when one or two alphabet is typed into the input box. But I cannot figure out how to enable the same by entering three alphabets. (For instance, input 'tsu' > output 'つ')

```
"u":"う", // <- can convert
"ku":"く", // <- can convert
"tsu":"つ", // <- cannot convert!
```

In the javascript code, there is a `var` called `dualLetter`, which goes by the following script:

```
var dualLetter = latreplaced[curLetter + pos1Txt];
```

How can I edit this part of code (or the entire javascript) to be able to convert **3 or more** input alphabets? Do I need to make `var tripleLetter`, or create a whole new system? Any alternative ways would also be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [edit] a solution inspired by your code :

I changed the main function but this definitively works

live demo : https://jsfiddle.net/alias_gui3/wds426mq/12/

source code :

```js
  var dictionnary = {
    "u":"う",
    "ku":"く",
    "tsu":"つ",
    
    "test for spaces": ""
  };
  
  var maxLength = Object.keys(dictionnary)
    .reduce((a, b) => a.length > b.length ? a : b) // get the longest word
    .length; // and it's length
  
  function translate (text) {
    var translated = "";
    var cur = 0;
    while (cur < text.length) {
      var testedPhoneme;
      var symbol = undefined;
      for (var length = maxLength; length > 0; length --) {
        testedPhoneme = text.substr(cur, length);
        if (dictionnary[testedPhoneme]) {
          symbol = dictionnary[testedPhoneme];
          break; // stop the loop
        }
      }
      if (symbol) {
        translated += symbol;
        cur += testedPhoneme.length;
      }
      else {
        translated += text[cur]
        cur++;
      }
    }
    return translated
  }

  function onLatinTextChange(txt) {
    var replacedTextareaElem = document.getElementById("replaced_textarea");
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    var replacedHtmlEntities = translate(txt);
    div.innerHTML = replacedHtmlEntities;
    replacedTextareaElem.value = div.innerText;
  }
```

---

### [previous post] a simple solution :

I suggest you split your text using spaces

If i understand well, you want to type `u ku tsu` to get `うくつ`, not `ukutsu`, if this is right then something like that could work :

```js
const dictionnary = {
  "u": "う",
  "ku": "く",
  "tsu": "つ"

var phonemes = text.split(' ') // split text by spaces
var translatedArray = phonemes.map(function (phoneme) {
  return dictionnary[phoneme] || phoneme 
  // will return the latin phoneme if it is not in the dictionnary
})
translatedString = translatedArray.join('')
```

Comment: Nope, the problem with the typer is that it cannot render つ at all because tsu contains three alphabets. So far the typer converts syllables up to two alphabets, but cannot from more than three alphabets.

Comment: ok, is 3 is the maximum length for a latin phoneme ?

Comment: I do not set a maximum length. In fact I wish it has no limits in length, because some characters require more than 3 alphabets for its transliteration.

Comment: But for now I'll just say 3 is the maximum, if it matters.

Comment: I added another solution on top of my answer, this is working whatever the words you put in the object **dictionnary** (even spaces)